# Represent 5 dim data with seaborn/matplotlib in scatter like plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Using seaborn lmplot with the hue option we can represent 3 dimensional data e.g. 3 variables: total_bill, tip and smoker:

```
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
>>> tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
>>> g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='smoker', data=tips, fit_reg=False)
```

How can I represent in the same scatter plot one more categorical dimension changing e.g the form of the bullet ?

Even more is it possible to represent 2 more categorical variables using different bullet shapes and the 5th using the size of the bullet/shape ?

Comment: Projections on lower dimension subspaces are certainly more readable. I doubt there is any case in which you'd detect patterns w.r.t. 5 variables at once represented in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent up to five dimensions with faceting:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
           hue="time", col="sex", row="smoker",
           size=3, data=tips)
```

[image]

You can also vary the markers, but they are varied with the color and not independently of it. As @JulienD pointed out, it's extremely hard for the human visual system to actually decode patterns from data where three variables are represented independently with color, marker, and size. It's much better practice to make multiple plots with lower dimensional projections.